# How do I return a value if the prepare statement fails in the below code?

Tags: perl, perl-module

```
sub loadFileRecon {
    my $self = shift;
    my $days = shift;
    if($days eq '') {
        $days = 1;
    }
    my $insert = $self->{rba}->rbdb->prepare(q{
        insert into rba.filerecon (
            filename,
            records,
            start_dtm,
            file_type,
            managed_file_id,
            mf_dtm,
            processed_tidemark,
            mm_records,
            mm_dropped,
            mm_erred,
            mm_duplicate,
            file_source
        )
        select
            i.filename,
            i.records,
            i.file_dtm start_dtm,
            i.file_type,
            mf.managed_file_id,
            mf.created_dtm mf_dtm,
            NULL,
            i.orig_records,
            i.dropped,
            i.erred,
            i.duplicate,
            i.file_source
        from rba.mmfilestats i, managedfile mf, filelog fl
        where
            i.filename = fl.file_name and
            trunc(i.file_dtm) = trunc(sysdate - ?) and
            mf.managed_file_id = fl.managed_file_id
    }) or die $DBI::errstr;
    $insert->execute($days);
    $insert->finish;
    $self->{rba}->rbdb->commit;
    my $update = $self->{rba}->rbdb->prepare(q{
        update rba.filerecon fr
        set processed_tidemark = (
            select processed_tidemark
            from jobhasfile j
            where j.managed_file_id = fr.managed_file_id
        )
        where
            trunc(start_dtm) = trunc(sysdate - ?) and
            processed_tidemark is null
    });
    $update->execute($days);
    $insert->finish;
    $self->{rba}->rbdb->commit;
}
```

If the prepare statement above fails due to table or view not existing, then it should return a value to perl module

Comment: Have you tried using `return`?

Comment: DBI can be configured to return errors instead of thrown exceptions using `RaiseError => 0`

Answer (score 1):

you are telling your program to die if the `prepare` returns false:

```
   }) or die $DBI::errstr;
```

replace that with what you're looking for:

```
   }) or return $somevalue;
```

or remove the `or` entirely and check the value of your statement handle;

```
   my $insert = $self->{rba}->rbdb->prepare(q{       
      ...
   });
   return $somevalue if ( !$insert );
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is return the DBI::errstr. Do not die on error.
So do something like this  (starting at your prepare and ending with your where but getting rid of the "or die"):

```
    ...prepare( ......

    where
        i.filename = fl.file_name and
        trunc(i.file_dtm) = trunc(sysdate - ?) and
        mf.managed_file_id = fl.managed_file_id
    });

    if ($DBI::errstr) {
        # oops something is wrong
        print $DBI::errstr;
        call_error($DBI::errstr);
    }
```

Good luck

Comment: none of the ideas worked for me... here is the errorlog             INFORM----PlugPointItem.pm:0282:20/12/12 23:15:24 > Calling loadFileRecon of type 'method' with 1 
DBD::Oracle::st execute failed: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist (DBD ERROR: error possibly near <*> indicator at char 409 in 'insert into rba.filerecon (filename,records,start_dtm,file_type,
managed_file_id, mf_dtm,processed_tidemark,            rds, i.dropped, i.erred, i.duplicate, i.file_source ...
from mf.managed_file_id=fl.manged_fle_id" with ParamValues: :p1='1'] at /opt/inftmov/rba/libs/custom/cRevPlugs.pm line 113.

Comment: I'm new to perl and not sure whether it is failing at prepare or execute. All I need is -1 should be returned in case of any insert failues due to duplicate records or for any table doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

Your post of the errorlog shows that your error is raised at point of execute not at the point of prepare.
So this what you do AFTER the execute:

```
    #your execute statement first
    $insert->execute($days);
    #Now the check on the execute
    if ($DBI::errstr) {
       # oops something is wrong
       return -1;
    }
```

Please let me know if this works

Comment: Thank you very much joe, but i tried this earlier also but didnot work anyways i gave an another trial and it is the same still.

Comment: I changed my code as follows to know if it is executing anything after the execute                                                  print 'Executing query';
        $insert->execute($days);
        print 'error';
        if ($DBI::errstr)
        {
           # oops something is wrong
           return -1;
        }
        $insert->finish;

Comment: The program is abruptly exiting immediately after query failed and not even a single statement is executed after the execute statement. I'm pasting the log information also where it printed the statement before execute and just ignored the one after.

Comment: Executing queryDBD::Oracle::st execute failed: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist (DBD ERROR: error possibly near <*> indicator at char 409 in 'insert into rba.filerecon (filename,records,start_dtm,file_type, managed_file_id, mf_dtm,processed_tidemark,mm_records,mm_dropped,mm_erred,mm_duplicat...i.dropped,i.erred,i.duplicate,i.file_source from rba.mmfilestats i, managedfile mf, filelog fl where
i.filename=fl.file_name and trrunc(i.file_dtm)=trunc(sysdate - ?)and
mf.managed_file_id=fl.managed_file_id" with ParamValues: :p1='1'] at /opt/inftmov/rba/libs/custom/cRevPlugs.pm line 108.

Comment: Hi, I assume you have removed the "or die...." statements? and instead you are doing something like prepare(...); if ($DBI::errstr ne '') {....}. Also you have printed $DBI::errstr immediately after prepare and immediately after execute. Can you please paste the headers of your perl script including where you "use DBI", prepare and execute? BTW do you actually have a scripot that works? Just asking to check your environment is a working environment.